# WPF DataGrid ItemSource Refresh - GridColumns shows strange behaviour

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I am developing WPF UserControl based on WPF DataGrid, to support dynamic column generation with our own business based context menu.

I've created Dependency Property called DataSource, when I set DataSource calling a custom method to Bind my dataSource to Create columns on the fly and set ItemSource property.  All works fine the first time.  I have a context menu called Refresh, while the user clicks Refresh the SQL will execute and the same cycle of the above-mentioned actions will happen.  During the second time, the rows and columns are created perfectly.  But when I do Horizontal scroll the Column headers are NOT showing properly, it loses their visual state while scrolling.

**My Custom Property - DataSource**

```
 public static DependencyProperty DataSourceProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("DataSource", typeof(GridDataModel), typeof(MyGridView),
      new PropertyMetadata((dependencyObject, eventArgs) =>
      {
          if (eventArgs.OldValue != null)
          {
              ((GridDataModel)eventArgs.OldValue).Dispose();
          }
          BindToDataSource((MyGridView)dependencyObject, (GridDataModel)eventArgs.NewValue);              
      }));
```

**My Custom method which is calling everytime I set DataSource property:**

```
 private static void BindToDataSource(MyGridView view, GridDataModel dataModel)
    {
        if (view.ViewModel != null)
        {               
            BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings(view.GridView);
            view.GridView.Items.Clear();                
            view.GridView.Columns.Clear();                
            view.GridView.ItemsSource = null;                
            view.ViewModel.Dispose();                
        }
        view.ViewModel = new MyGridViewModel(dataModel);
        view.ViewModel.PrepareGridView();
        view.LayoutRoot.DataContext = view.ViewModel;
        view.CreateColumns();                        
        view.GridView.SetBinding(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("DisplayRows"));
    }
```

**The Below code I used to call on Refresh Menu Click:**

```
    private void OnRefreshClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var data = new TestDataAccess();
       DataSource = data.MakeGridModel("select  Top 200 * from ApplicationUSer"); //Assigning DataSource Again, which will call the above method.
        GridView.UpdateLayout();
    }
```

After refresh, you could see the column alignment goes strange when doing the horizontal scroll.

Tried using GridColumnWidth =0, and setting again to Auto, Tried GridView.UpdateLayout().

Answer (score 1):

I solved the above problem my self.

Instead of BindingOperations.ClearAllBindings() i used BindingOperations.ClearBinding(view.GridView, DataGrid.ItemSourceProperty) - which cleared out only ItemSource so that i can regain memory by Items.Clear() for every time i bind the data.

Due to ClearAllBindings, its clears headers panel bindings also, so its looses ParentTemplate.Width property, because of that strange problem happend during horizontal scroll.